# How do I get data from jQuery looping from view blade in controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

this is view blade How do I get data from jQuery looping from view blade in controller

```
$('.abc:checked').each(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'TEST',

        data: {

            '_token': token,
            'ruledetail': $(this).attr("name"),
            'rule': $(this).attr("data"),
            'amount': $(this).attr("amount"),
            'total': total,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

and this is  my controller i try get data and seperate it from looping

```
public function testsenddata(Request $request)
{
    $get = array(
        'ruledetail' => 'ruledetail',
        'rule' => 'rule',
        'amount' => 'amount',
        'total' => 'total',
        // 'value' => 'value',
    );
    $t = $request->ruledetail;
    $t2 = $request->rule;
    $t3 = $request->amount;
    $t4 = $request->total;

    return response()->json(['data1' => $t,'data2' => $t2,'data' => $t3,'total' => $t4]);
}
```

it's possible? and sorry for my english

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here? You mention a controller but there's no controller code.

Comment: sorry i've edited pls take a look again thanks